# CFHTTP call to (Java) REST based API returning application/json fails

Tags: api, rest, coldfusion, mime-types, cfhttp

I am using `cfhttp` to access a remote API (on different server) which is returning an `application/json` in the response. The API is working fine with the Postman client. But using the API with ColdFusion is giving 2 errors:

- **file content is [empty_string]** *and also*
- **unable to determine mime type**

I have used almost everything suggested in blogs:

- [CFHTTP "Could Not Determine MIME Type of File" Error with FacebookGraph API](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2010/10/cfhttp-not-determine-mime-type-of-file.html)
- [CFHTTP connection problems](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?473374-CFHTTP-connection-problems)

Comment: Can you show us some code. Especially the `cfhttp` part.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `cfhttpparam` like this:

```
<cfhttp url="***url***" method="GET" result="res">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="mimetype" value="application/json" />
</cfhttp>
```